# Exception configuring failed request tracing rule

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-10, windows-server-2019

[image]
Getting the following error clicking finish on the Add Failed Request Tracing Rule in IIS v10.0.17763.1 running on Windows Server 2019...

> There was an error while performing this operation.
>
> Details:
>
> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CEF03

The web.config looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
       <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="fred">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false">
              <tokenRequestParameters>
                <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                </trust:SecondaryParameters>
              </tokenRequestParameters>
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

If you change the config to this the problem goes away...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
       <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="fred">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false">
              <tokenRequestParameters>
              </tokenRequestParameters>
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I can't see anything wrong with the XML causing the issue.  Is this a bug?

Comment: The error means some part of web.config is incorrect or damaged. Have you tried publish the application again and then add frt rules?

Comment: frt rules?  Not sure what you mean.  Anyhow, I've replicated this problem on three different machines, two 2019 servers, and my windows 10 desktop.  Copying and pasting the config above reproduces, you saying you can't replicate it?

Comment: I never say I can't replicate it. As you said, this issue really exists and I have reproduced it. FRT rule is Failed Request Tracing rule. I want to know the version of IIS that web.config can work because the oldest version I can test is IIS8.5 on server 2012R2. It cannot work, too.

Comment: IIS Manager source code is almost the same, except that IIS Manager on IIS 7.5 uses .NET Framework 3.5 while on iIS 8.5 uses .NET Framework 4.x. So I assume the XML validation difference comes from .NET Framework itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a bug of IIS. Maybe it is by designed, maybe the new version of IIS did not consider backward compatibility during development, maybe some xml elements have has been deprecated by Microsoft but it is not stated in the relevant documentation. Anyway, I have reported the issue to Microsoft and IIS team. I'll let you know the result once I hear from them.